# Hibernate One To One Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Now, i am learning hibernate, and started to using it in my project. It is a CRUD application. I used hibernate for all the crud operations. It works for all of them. But, the One-To-One, i am tired of trying it. Finally it gives me the below error.

`Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.ppbni.splatter.model.Wafat, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(wafatDetail)]`

this is my useradmin model,

```
package org.ppbni.splatter.model;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserAdmin {

private String no_dana;
private String npp;
private String password;
private String nama_depan;
private String nama_tengah;
private String nama_belakang;
private String agama;
private String jenis_kelamin;
private Date tgl_lahir; 
private String alamat;
private String rt;
private String rw;
private String kelurahan;
private String kecamatan;
private String kota;
private String kode_pos;
private String propinsi;
private String no_telepon;
private String no_handphone_1;
private String no_handphone_2;
private String display_name;
private Date tgl_gabung;
private Date last_login;
private Integer enabled;
private String status;
private String unit_terakhir;
private String jabatan_terakhir;
private String pangkat_terakhir;
private String authority;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="no_dana", unique=true, nullable=false)
public String getNo_dana() {
    return no_dana;
}
public void setNo_dana(String no_dana) {
    this.no_dana = no_dana;
}
@Column(name="npp")
public String getNpp() {
    return npp;
}
public void setNpp(String npp) {
    this.npp = npp;
}
@Column(name="password")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
@Column(name="nama_depan")
public String getNama_depan() {
    return nama_depan;
}
public void setNama_depan(String nama_depan) {
    this.nama_depan = nama_depan;
}
@Column(name="nama_tengah")
public String getNama_tengah() {
    return nama_tengah;
}
public void setNama_tengah(String nama_tengah) {
    this.nama_tengah = nama_tengah;
}
@Column(name="nama_belakang")
public String getNama_belakang() {
    return nama_belakang;
}
public void setNama_belakang(String nama_belakang) {
    this.nama_belakang = nama_belakang;
}
@Column(name="agama")
public String getAgama() {
    return agama;
}
public void setAgama(String agama) {
    this.agama = agama;
}
@Column(name="jenis_kelamin")
public String getJenis_kelamin() {
    return jenis_kelamin;
}
public void setJenis_kelamin(String jenis_kelamin) {
    this.jenis_kelamin = jenis_kelamin;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "tgl_lahir")
public Date getTgl_lahir() {
    return tgl_lahir;
}
public void setTgl_lahir(Date tgl_lahir) {
    this.tgl_lahir = tgl_lahir;
}

@Column(name="alamat")
public String getAlamat() {
    return alamat;
}
public void setAlamat(String alamat) {
    this.alamat = alamat;
}

@Column(name="rt")
public String getRt() {
    return rt;
}
public void setRt(String rt) {
    this.rt = rt;
}
@Column(name="rw")
public String getRw() {
    return rw;
}
public void setRw(String rw) {
    this.rw = rw;
}

@Column(name="kelurahan")
public String getKelurahan() {
    return kelurahan;
}
public void setKelurahan(String kelurahan) {
    this.kelurahan = kelurahan;
}

@Column(name="kecamatan")
public String getKecamatan() {
    return kecamatan;
}
public void setKecamatan(String kecamatan) {
    this.kecamatan = kecamatan;
}

@Column(name="kota")
public String getKota() {
    return kota;
}
public void setKota(String kota) {
    this.kota = kota;
}

@Column(name="kode_pos")
public String getKode_pos() {
    return kode_pos;
}
public void setKode_pos(String kode_pos) {
    this.kode_pos = kode_pos;
}

@Column(name="propinsi")
public String getPropinsi() {
    return propinsi;
}
public void setPropinsi(String propinsi) {
    this.propinsi = propinsi;
}

@Column(name="no_telepon")
public String getNo_telepon() {
    return no_telepon;
}
public void setNo_telepon(String no_telepon) {
    this.no_telepon = no_telepon;
}
@Column(name="no_handphone_1")
public String getNo_handphone_1() {
    return no_handphone_1;
}
public void setNo_handphone_1(String no_handphone_1) {
    this.no_handphone_1 = no_handphone_1;
}

@Column(name="no_handphone_2")
public String getNo_handphone_2() {
    return no_handphone_2;
}
public void setNo_handphone_2(String no_handphone_2) {
    this.no_handphone_2 = no_handphone_2;
}

@Column(name="display_name")
public String getDisplay_name() {
    return display_name;
}
public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
    this.display_name = display_name;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "tgl_gabung")
public Date getTgl_gabung() {
    return tgl_gabung;
}
public void setTgl_gabung(Date tgl_gabung) {
    this.tgl_gabung = tgl_gabung;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "last_login")
public Date getLast_login() {
    return last_login;
}
public void setLast_login(Date last_login) {
    this.last_login = last_login;
}
@Column(name="enabled")
public Integer getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
public void setEnabled(Integer enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
@Column(name="status")
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
@Column(name="unit_terakhir")
public String getUnit_terakhir() {
    return unit_terakhir;
}
public void setUnit_terakhir(String unit_terakhir) {
    this.unit_terakhir = unit_terakhir;
}
@Column(name="jabatan_terakhir")
public String getJabatan_terakhir() {
    return jabatan_terakhir;
}
public void setJabatan_terakhir(String jabatan_terakhir) {
    this.jabatan_terakhir = jabatan_terakhir;
}
@Column(name="pangkat_terakhir")
public String getPangkat_terakhir() {
    return pangkat_terakhir;
}
public void setPangkat_terakhir(String pangkat_terakhir) {
    this.pangkat_terakhir = pangkat_terakhir;
}
@Column(name="authority")
public String getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}
public void setAuthority(String authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}

@OneToOne(mappedBy="useradmin", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Wafat wafat;

public Wafat getWafat(){
    return wafat;
}

public void setWafat(Wafat wafat){
    this.wafat = wafat;
}

/**
 * @param args
 */

}
```

this is my wafat model,

```
package org.ppbni.splatter.model;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;

@Entity
@Table(name="wafat")
public class Wafat {

private String kode_wafat;
private String no_dana;
private Date tgl_wafat;
private int usia_wafat;
private Date tgl_makam;
private String tempat_makam;

@Id
@Column(name="kode_wafat", unique=true, nullable=false)
public String getKode_wafat() {
    return kode_wafat;
}
public void setKode_wafat(String kode_wafat) {
    this.kode_wafat = kode_wafat;
}
@Id
@Column(name="no_dana", unique=true, nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
@GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="user"))
public String getNo_dana() {
    return no_dana;
}
public void setNo_dana(String no_dana) {
    this.no_dana = no_dana;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="tgl_wafat")
public Date getTgl_wafat() {
    return tgl_wafat;
}
public void setTgl_wafat(Date tgl_wafat) {
    this.tgl_wafat = tgl_wafat;
}
@Column(name="usia_wafat")
public int getUsia_wafat() {
    return usia_wafat;
}
public void setUsia_wafat(int usia_wafat) {
    this.usia_wafat = usia_wafat;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="tgl_makam")
public Date getTgl_makam() {
    return tgl_makam;
}
public void setTgl_makam(Date tgl_makam) {
    this.tgl_makam = tgl_makam;
}
@Column(name="tempat_makam")
public String getTempat_makam() {
    return tempat_makam;
}
public void setTempat_makam(String tempat_makam) {
    this.tempat_makam = tempat_makam;
}

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private UserAdmin useradmin;

/**
 * @param args
 */

}
```

and this is my controller,

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RequestMapping("/berita-duka.html")
public ModelAndView listAllWafat(ModelMap model)throws Exception{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("beritaduka");

    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    List<UserAdmin> useradmin = session.createQuery("from UserAdmin").list();
    for (UserAdmin useradmin1 : useradmin){
        System.out.println(useradmin1.getNama_tengah() + " , "
                + useradmin1.getKota() + ", "
                + useradmin1.getWafat().getKode_wafat());
    }

    session.close();
    factory.close();

    return mav;

}
```

another exception :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path    [/PPBNI] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at       org.ppbni.splatter.web.controller.GenController.listAllWafat(GenController.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `mappedBy="useradmin"` Instead.

Comment: When you define the wafat attribute, you map  `@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)`, but there's no attribute use in Wafat entity. Did you mean "useradmin"?

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I was changed into `mappedBy='useradmin'` and still show same error

Comment: @Jodevan same error for `mappedBy='useradmin'` ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have got your mapping wrong  and wanted to have `OneToOne` mapping between `UserAdmin` and `Wafat` class with both share the same primary key.

If so, you may want to try with the following mapping with `MapsId` and `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotations.

**UserAdmin.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
class UserAdmin implements Serializable {

private int no_dana;
private String npp;
private String password;
private String nama_depan;
private String nama_tengah;
private String nama_belakang;
private String agama;
private String jenis_kelamin;
private Date tgl_lahir; 
private String alamat;
private String rt;
private String rw;
private String kelurahan;
private String kecamatan;
private String kota;
private String kode_pos;
private String propinsi;
private String no_telepon;
private String no_handphone_1;
private String no_handphone_2;
private String display_name;
private Date tgl_gabung;
private Date last_login;
private Integer enabled;
private String status;
private String unit_terakhir;
private String jabatan_terakhir;
private String pangkat_terakhir;
private String authority;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="no_dana", unique=true, nullable=false)
public int getNo_dana() {
    return no_dana;
}
public void setNo_dana(int no_dana) {
    this.no_dana = no_dana;
}
@Column(name="npp")
public String getNpp() {
    return npp;
}
public void setNpp(String npp) {
    this.npp = npp;
}
@Column(name="password")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
@Column(name="nama_depan")
public String getNama_depan() {
    return nama_depan;
}
public void setNama_depan(String nama_depan) {
    this.nama_depan = nama_depan;
}
@Column(name="nama_tengah")
public String getNama_tengah() {
    return nama_tengah;
}
public void setNama_tengah(String nama_tengah) {
    this.nama_tengah = nama_tengah;
}
@Column(name="nama_belakang")
public String getNama_belakang() {
    return nama_belakang;
}
public void setNama_belakang(String nama_belakang) {
    this.nama_belakang = nama_belakang;
}
@Column(name="agama")
public String getAgama() {
    return agama;
}
public void setAgama(String agama) {
    this.agama = agama;
}
@Column(name="jenis_kelamin")
public String getJenis_kelamin() {
    return jenis_kelamin;
}
public void setJenis_kelamin(String jenis_kelamin) {
    this.jenis_kelamin = jenis_kelamin;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "tgl_lahir")
public Date getTgl_lahir() {
    return tgl_lahir;
}
public void setTgl_lahir(Date tgl_lahir) {
    this.tgl_lahir = tgl_lahir;
}

@Column(name="alamat")
public String getAlamat() {
    return alamat;
}
public void setAlamat(String alamat) {
    this.alamat = alamat;
}

@Column(name="rt")
public String getRt() {
    return rt;
}
public void setRt(String rt) {
    this.rt = rt;
}
@Column(name="rw")
public String getRw() {
    return rw;
}
public void setRw(String rw) {
    this.rw = rw;
}

@Column(name="kelurahan")
public String getKelurahan() {
    return kelurahan;
}
public void setKelurahan(String kelurahan) {
    this.kelurahan = kelurahan;
}

@Column(name="kecamatan")
public String getKecamatan() {
    return kecamatan;
}
public void setKecamatan(String kecamatan) {
    this.kecamatan = kecamatan;
}

@Column(name="kota")
public String getKota() {
    return kota;
}
public void setKota(String kota) {
    this.kota = kota;
}

@Column(name="kode_pos")
public String getKode_pos() {
    return kode_pos;
}
public void setKode_pos(String kode_pos) {
    this.kode_pos = kode_pos;
}

@Column(name="propinsi")
public String getPropinsi() {
    return propinsi;
}
public void setPropinsi(String propinsi) {
    this.propinsi = propinsi;
}

@Column(name="no_telepon")
public String getNo_telepon() {
    return no_telepon;
}
public void setNo_telepon(String no_telepon) {
    this.no_telepon = no_telepon;
}
@Column(name="no_handphone_1")
public String getNo_handphone_1() {
    return no_handphone_1;
}
public void setNo_handphone_1(String no_handphone_1) {
    this.no_handphone_1 = no_handphone_1;
}

@Column(name="no_handphone_2")
public String getNo_handphone_2() {
    return no_handphone_2;
}
public void setNo_handphone_2(String no_handphone_2) {
    this.no_handphone_2 = no_handphone_2;
}

@Column(name="display_name")
public String getDisplay_name() {
    return display_name;
}
public void setDisplay_name(String display_name) {
    this.display_name = display_name;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "tgl_gabung")
public Date getTgl_gabung() {
    return tgl_gabung;
}
public void setTgl_gabung(Date tgl_gabung) {
    this.tgl_gabung = tgl_gabung;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "last_login")
public Date getLast_login() {
    return last_login;
}
public void setLast_login(Date last_login) {
    this.last_login = last_login;
}
@Column(name="enabled")
public Integer getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
public void setEnabled(Integer enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
@Column(name="status")
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
@Column(name="unit_terakhir")
public String getUnit_terakhir() {
    return unit_terakhir;
}
public void setUnit_terakhir(String unit_terakhir) {
    this.unit_terakhir = unit_terakhir;
}
@Column(name="jabatan_terakhir")
public String getJabatan_terakhir() {
    return jabatan_terakhir;
}
public void setJabatan_terakhir(String jabatan_terakhir) {
    this.jabatan_terakhir = jabatan_terakhir;
}
@Column(name="pangkat_terakhir")
public String getPangkat_terakhir() {
    return pangkat_terakhir;
}
public void setPangkat_terakhir(String pangkat_terakhir) {
    this.pangkat_terakhir = pangkat_terakhir;
}
@Column(name="authority")
public String getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}
public void setAuthority(String authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}

private Wafat wafat;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="useradmin", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public Wafat getWafat(){
    return wafat;
}

public void setWafat(Wafat wafat){
    this.wafat = wafat;
}
```

**Wafat.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="wafat")
class Wafat implements Serializable{

private String kode_wafat;
private int no_dana;
private Date tgl_wafat;
private int usia_wafat;
private Date tgl_makam;
private String tempat_makam;

@Column(name="kode_wafat", unique=true, nullable=false)
public String getKode_wafat() {
    return kode_wafat;
}
public void setKode_wafat(String kode_wafat) {
    this.kode_wafat = kode_wafat;
}
@Id
@JoinColumn(name="no_dana")
public int getNo_dana() {
    return no_dana;
}
public void setNo_dana(int no_dana) {
    this.no_dana = no_dana;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="tgl_wafat")
public Date getTgl_wafat() {
    return tgl_wafat;
}
public void setTgl_wafat(Date tgl_wafat) {
    this.tgl_wafat = tgl_wafat;
}
@Column(name="usia_wafat")
public int getUsia_wafat() {
    return usia_wafat;
}
public void setUsia_wafat(int usia_wafat) {
    this.usia_wafat = usia_wafat;
}
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="tgl_makam")
public Date getTgl_makam() {
    return tgl_makam;
}
public void setTgl_makam(Date tgl_makam) {
    this.tgl_makam = tgl_makam;
}
@Column(name="tempat_makam")
public String getTempat_makam() {
    return tempat_makam;
}
public void setTempat_makam(String tempat_makam) {
    this.tempat_makam = tempat_makam;
}

private UserAdmin useradmin;

@OneToOne
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name="no_dana")
public UserAdmin getUseradmin() {
    return useradmin;
}
public void setUseradmin(UserAdmin useradmin) {
    this.useradmin = useradmin;
}

}
```

And to save the entities:

```
UserAdmin ua = new UserAdmin();
Wafat w = new Wafat();
w.setKode_wafat("Kode_Wafat");
ua.setWafat(w);
w.setUseradmin(ua);
session.persist(ua);
```

Some suggestions:

1. You have mixed hibernate annotations on field and property . Stick to one approach, either set  hibernate annotations on field or property.
2. If understand that you are learning hibernate, so I suggest try with smaller classes first. Too many fields and it might confuse you.

Comment: wohhh, the error was gone, but when I trying all list data  get null pointer 'List<UserAdmin> useradmin = session.createQuery("from UserAdmin").list();
  for (UserAdmin useradmin1 : useradmin){
   System.out.println(useradmin1.getNama_tengah() + " , "
     + useradmin1.getKota() + ", "
     + useradmin1.getWafat().getKode_wafat());
  }'

Comment: @splatter_fadli I tried your above code to list the data and it is working for me. Do you have `session` variable intialized? Post the stacktrace if you still face the error.

Comment: @splatter_fadli Post the exception. I see that you are opening & closing sessionfactory, which is not recommended. More over since it is spring MVC app you don't even need to create SessionFactory. Use spring to do that and autowire it. If the intent is to try only Hibernate, I would recommend testing it as a standalone java unless you already are comfortable with Spring MVC.

Comment: Okay, I have posted it ~

Comment: @splatter_fadli Check what is at line 62. I doubt if session or sessionFactory is null. Do a sysout of these two variables and check. I would recommend testing it as a standalone java app, unless you already are comfortable with Spring MVC. If you want to continue with Spring MVC please integrate Hibernate with Spring following some good tutorial should help.

Comment: no, line 62 is `useradmin1.getWafat().getKode_wafat()`, session and sessionFactory are fine  ~

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108072/discussion-between-madhusudana-reddy-sunnapu-and-splatter-fadli).